# Haskell overlapping instances and type functions

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, typeclass, overlapping-instances

I have the following typeclass which models a SQL-like query optimization:

```
class OptimizableQuery q where
  type Optimized q :: *
  optimize :: q -> Optimized q

instance Query q => OptimizableQuery q where
  type Optimized q = q
  optimize q = q

instance (Query q, OptimizableQuery q) => OptimizableQuery (Select (Select q p) p) where
  type Optimized (Select (Select q p) p) = Select (Optimized q) p
  optimize (Select (Select q _) p) = Select (optimize q) p
```

the problem is that I get the error "Conflicting family instance declarations" on the Optimized type function. Why is that and how can I solve it? It would really be nice to have a "fallback instance" instead of having to exhaust all cases (which might be quite many)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's illegal to have overlapping instances with type families. See the [GHC manual](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#type-instance-declarations), "Overlap of type synonym instances" for details.

The reason is that having two different possible results for a type function application depending on the available instances can lead to unsoundness.

Comment: I can't think of any workarounds apart from exhausting all cases. Sorry!